# Return dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple data layer routine that performs a password update, the user passes in the following:

- Current Password, New Password, Confirm New Password.

In my data layer (proc) checks a couple things such as:

1. Is the current password correct?
2. Is the new password and confirm password correct?
3. Has the new password been assigned in the past?

And so on...

Now I know I can simply create a class and returned a couple booleans:

```
public class UpdatePasswordResponse{

public bool CurrentPasswordCorrect {get;set;}
....(and so on)

}
```

But is there a way I can dynamically return that information to the biz layer in properties  instead of creating a new class everytime (for every data layer routine)? I seem to remember thinking this was possible. I am pretty sure I read it somewhere but don't remember the syntax, can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to use a static class (no need to initialize)?

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to use dynamics for this functionality? Wrapper class and well-design application would be much faster.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason not to, I would avoid creating dynamic objects to return.  Strongly Type objects are good things.  Just make sure you're passing them via an interface to practice loose coupling of layers.

Comment: Thank you all the for quick response. I like the idea of using a Tuple to return the data.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do this in .NET 4 with the use of the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword.

The class you will want to return would be an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Basically, follow this pattern:

```
public object GetDynamicObject()
{
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    obj.DynamicProperty1 = "hello world";
    obj.DynamicProperty2 = 123;
    return obj;
}


// elsewhere in your code:

dynamic myObj = GetDynamicObject();
string hello = myObj.DynamicProperty1;
```

Comment: He could do this, but would you really suggest use of an Expando in this situation?  I'd almost rather see him use a Tuple.

Comment: A Tuple would work too. I assumed he wanted to arbitrarily name his properties.

Comment: As Mattias points out, a simple anonymous class would work as well, but would also be "set in stone" in terms of which properties were on the object.

Comment: @Randolpho I always forget about Tuples...although I rarely have cause to return an anonymous object.

Comment: When trying this code, I get the error `'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'DynamicProperty1' ...`
The line: `var obj = new ExpandoObject();` should be changed to `dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();` and then it works as expected

Comment: This worked for me. even to return an Json.

    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    obj.DynamicProperty1 = "hello world";
    obj.DynamicProperty2 = 123;
    

       var jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
                return jsonOutput;

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to dynamically create a class you write:

```
public object MyMethod()
{
     var result = new { Username = "my name", Password = "the password" };
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you just create an `anonymous` instance? not a `dynamic` one?

Comment: I've tried this but I am not able to access Properties by calling MyMethod. How do I access it?

Comment: var expResult = new MyMethod();
string usrName = expResult.GetType().GetProperty("Username").GetValue(expResult);